# Datagrid Column value bind?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to accept only specific digits into a column in datagrid how can i handle it?

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=SellingPrice, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
 <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
     <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="10"/>
  </Style>
 </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

in above code i have given Value="10", I need to bind the value from ViewModel how can i do it

Comment: is it working?what is the error

Comment: When i give the value directly as 10 then in my datagrid column is accepting 10 digits only but i need to give value from my Viewmodel but not directly how it is possible?

Comment: add a check on SellingPrice get or set property

Comment: sorry,can you please say clearly. What exactly i need to do to solve this.

Comment: you are binding **SellingPrice** with your column.so in your **getter** you can add a check and return only 10 digits

Comment: Exactly what i need is when i enter in the column of my datagrid it should accept only certain length(i.e. the length which i will assign in my viewmodel)

Comment: i need to enter my value from front end so if i enter more than 10 digits it should not allow like enter value should not be seen

Comment: do this `<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
     <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="{Binding Path=length"/>
  </Style>`

Comment: `length` is your property.you can assign any value.and your column will allow only that many digits

Comment: please can any one help me?

Comment: Note that length should be a public  property that NotifyPropertyChange in Setter.

Comment: private int _len;
        public int length
        {
            get
            {
                return _len;
            }
            set
            {
                _len = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("length");

            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test this at the moment, but you may have to do this in your style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyMaxLength"/>
</Style>
```

Where `MyMaxLength` is a property on your bound object.